# Why node.js server doesn't exit after script done?

Tags: node.js, webserver

Why node.js app created as a web server via *http.createServer* doesn't exit after end as simple *console.log()* app?
Is it because there is a forever *while true {}* cycle somewhere in http module?

Comment: because you do not close the http server. doing so would terminate the application.

Answer (score 2):

Deep in the internals of Node.js there is bookkeeping being done. The number of active event listeners is being counted. Events and event-driven programming model are what make Node.js special. Events are also the life blood that keep a Node.js program alive.

A Node.js program will keep running as long as there are active event listeners present. After the last event listener has finished or otherwise terminated the Node.js program will also terminate.

For more details
[GO HERE](https://thisbythis.com/mynotes/why-does-console-log-exit-but-http-server-doesnt.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is the core of node, that while waiting for new connections, to not exit. Without using loops

There are many other ways, to keep node running, without forever while. For example:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){},10000000)
```

Comment: And what about mongodb connection? which part of core does it use?

Comment: You asking about mongodb server or client? The mongodb client, will exitm when it complete all his tasks